Error using `\mathpalette`
I'm trying to create a macro for slightly reducing the size of characters in subscripts.
\newcommand{\smol}[1]{\mathpalette\@smol{#1}}
\newcommand{\@smol}[2]{{\scalebox{.6}{$#1#2$}}}

The characters scaled this way should be correctly diplayed in double subscripts, i.e.
\newcommand{\smol}[1]{\mathpalette\@smol{#1}}
\newcommand{\@smol}[2]{{\scalebox{.6}{$#1#2$}}}

\begin{document}

a_{b_\smol{C}}

\end{document}

However, the macro defined gives an error about missing {, } or $ characters.

You’re missing the enclosing $ characters and braces around \smol{C}.

No error if I use \makeatletter and \makeatother at the appropriate spots, $ to open and close the formula and braces around \smal{C}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smol}[1]{\mathpalette\@smol{#1}}
\newcommand{\@smol}[2]{{\scalebox{.6}{$#1#2$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a_{b_{\smol{C}}}$ and $a_{b_{c}}$

$b_{\smol{C}}$ and $b_{c}$

\end{document}

The result's not pretty, though, both because the C is much thinner and it's also very similar to a lowercase c.

You might consider lowering the capital C
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a_{b^{}_{C}}$ and $a_{b_{c}}$

$b^{}_{C}$ and $b_{c}$

\end{document}

A blank superscript does the job.

